# Google Cloud Functions and CORS

Tags: jquery, google-cloud-functions, cors

I'm trying to call my Google Cloud Function using a Jquery request. This is blocked by the browser because of the CORS policy. To overcome this I tried what is described in the docs of Google Cloud functions: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests. It says that CORS can be enabled using a preflight request.
To be precise, these are the first lines of my Cloud function:

```py
def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('', 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
```

I call the cloud function from my local client http://127.0.0.1:5000.
This is how I try to call the API, by first doing the preflight request and after that the actual API call:

```js
$(function () {
            console.log("starting preflight");
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://cloudfunction/recommend",
                type: "OPTIONS"
            }).always(function () {
                console.log("preflight done");
                $.post("https://cloudfunction/recommend", {
                    "some": "data"
                }).done(function (data) {
                    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                });
            });
        });
```

The preflight request seems to go well, however Chrome returns this error on the actual API (post) call: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cloudfunction/recommend' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I already tried setting `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` and `'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*'`, and combinations, but all resulted in the same error as above.

Does someone know what is going wrong here?